# Why does Windows 95 not install so well from a Windows XP boot floppy?

Tags: ms-dos, windows-95, windows-xp

EDIT: And *this* is why you shouldn't rely purely on memory for these sort of things. After some fiddling with my XP and Win95 disks, I remembered that the problems I was having were more likely related to how Windows XP was formatting the Windows 95 installation target drive, and I also discovered that the most recent version of VirtualBox won't let me do what I'm trying to do at all, so I think this whole question is actually due to me misremembering and possibly misunderstanding things, plus virtualization problems. Sorry about that, feel free to delete this if you'd like.

First, the anecdote that inspired this question.

Several years ago, I got the itch to try and install Windows 95 in a VM on my Windows 7 laptop. I had very little idea as to what I was doing at the time, and so attempted to boot the Windows 95 CD I had handy... at which point I promptly discovered that the CD wasn't bootable. It didn't take me long to remember from an old book I read that I was supposed to use DOS to run the setup program and install Windows that way, and I remembered from previous experience with Windows XP's bootable DOS disks that you couldn't access the CD drive from one, so I copied the Windows 95 CD contents to a partition on a virtual drive. Then I made a virtual floppy disk, inserted it into the VM, formatted it using the option to create a bootable disk, then proceeded to boot up my to-be-Win95 VM from the DOS disk and attempted to install.

Good grief that was the most convoluted installation I ever did. I don't remember a lot of details here, but people who have done this sort of thing probably know well what I'm talking about since it was easily reproducible. I intend on trying this installation again so I can be more specific about the mess.

First it threw an error message at me that I think was <strike>related to something about TSRs or some memory-related-something-or-other</strike>. (Actually, thinking about it more closely, I think the error was actually related to some sort of detected disk compression.) I think I had to use special switches to get the setup program to run. Then I believe it insisted on running ScanDisk before it would start the installation (?!). The installer finally did start, but it ended up crashing somewhere around the hardware detection part of the install. Upon attempting to install again, it allowed me to use some sort of safe mode, which allowed me to get past the hardware detection phase, and it was around this point that it gave me the option to create a bootable DOS disk for Windows 95. I ended up doing this, which was good because the installation process later crashed again with a general protection fault (I think). Trying to boot this halfway-installed Windows 95 using XP's DOS disk (by running WIN.COM from it) gave me a blue screen with some message about FAT, if I'm remembering right.

After this frustration, I finally tried to install Windows 95 all over again, but this time using the DOS disk created by the windows 95 installation procedure, rather than XP's DOS disk. This time everything just worked. No crashes, no glitches, just a typical OS installation process that ended with a working Windows 95 desktop and a very happy user. (I might have, out of paranoia, created a second Windows 95 DOS disk using the first one for fear that the first one might have been corrupted by the wonky XP DOS disk, but I don't think that was necessary and I think I skipped that when doing the same installation a different time.)

So now for the questions.

1. What in particular would cause Windows 95's Setup application to think there was disk compression involved somehow? I'm pretty sure that I was installing it to a blank disk, and had the setup files on a different disk.
2. What problems or differences in the DOS disk would cause the crashes? (Particularly the mysterious general protection fault, though the one that caused things to go awry during hardware detection would be interesting to know about too.)

(Bonus question though unrelated: When booting the Windows XP DOS disk, it would show an `A:\>` prompt at the top instead of a "Starting MS-DOS" message or some such. Underneath it would appear the real `A:\>` prompt. Why did that happen?)

Comment: You know that Windows XP was Windows NT? While win 95 and 98 not? They were completely different systems...

Comment: @Selvin Yes, of course, but I don't know why that should have any effect on how the bootable DOS floppy spit out by either should function. A DOS disk made by Win95 *should* work just like a DOS disk made by WinXP, IMO, since it's still DOS both times. Obviously that's not the case, though...

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 For a while, under NT, Microsoft wrote a *VERY* compatible DOS emulation and sustained it up through Windows XP 32-bit Pro. After that, they gave up and provided only a nearly worthless emulation. This was the moment when they shifted the emulation to no longer support 16-bit applications under their emulated DOS box (CMD.EXE.) You can easily test this. QB4.5 will run fine under XP. Won't run at all under later Windows versions.

Comment: @jonk I'm talking about the version of DOS that XP would place on a floppy disk if you created a bootable floppy disk. It came complete with COMMAND.COM and IO.SYS. Not the DOS emulation that came as part of the OS itself that would be used when trying to run DOS software on XP.

Comment: Can you bring that down to a simple answerable list of weirdnesses to answer? XP boot disk is for XP and is more related to ME boot disk. It has no CD-ROM drivers or any other drivers. And AUTOEXEC.BAT is an empty file which explains the two prompts. And you ran this under a VM which may complicate thing and allow things not generally possible. When installing Win95, you are sort of expected to start the install from officially compatible Win95 boot media, as WinXP certainly did not exist.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 I think the issues are related to each other. But I grant I may be wrong about it, too. It's partly why I didn't offer an answer.

Comment: @jonk The MS-DOS and Win16 emulation ([NTVDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine)) existed in all NT-based 32-bit x86 versions of Windows (3.1 through 10), never in any 64-bit version. I think it wasn't installed by default in 10. It has nothing to do with cmd.exe, which is a native 32/64-bit Windows application that happens to run in a console window. Anyway, this is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @benrg Agreed about the "never in any 64-bit version." But I'm talking exclusively about 32-bit versions of the O/S. I have a long track record of following the details of when the transition took place -- the loss of support for 16-bit application support on a variety of levels. I can unearth my web pages on this topic (they are old and retired now.) But I was there and watched it happen.

Comment: Unfortunately your updated list of weirdnesses to answer isn’t really answerable, at least not points (1) and (2) since they are based on your recollections from several years ago. If you really want answers to those points, you’d have to be able to confirm or infirm your “I think” comments, *i.e.* be able to accurately describe what really happened when you tried to install Windows 95. (I’m not saying things didn’t go wrong, Windows 95 could be difficult to install — Windows 98 was much better.)

Comment: I managed to reproduce (1), but not (2) in QEMU; I suspect the VM to be at fault for the latter. (3) is a trivial cosmetic issue due to a blank line in AUTOEXEC.BAT, as previously mentioned; not much to do with DOS itself. I’d suggest restricting the question to (1) and (4) and editing out the rest, as these are relatively easily answerable and related to each other, but not to others.

Comment: @StephenKitt I still have all of the software and disks on me, so it wouldn't be too tricky to reproduce, and at least one person was able to reproduce one of the problems. I'll try the installation process again in the (hopefully) near future and update with specifics.

Comment: @user3840170 Hmm, when I first did this I was using VirtualBox as my virtualization software. However, I tried again later using QEMU (with KVM, not pure emulation) and all the same symptoms happened there too. I wonder if using pure emulation mode would make a difference? (I learned the hard way that it really makes a difference when you tried to boot the finished install with KVM, since Win95 is grumpy with fast CPUs, *grr...*)

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 TCG mode in QEMU usually works somewhat *worse*; it takes some shortcuts for the sake of not slowing down modern operating systems which do not exercise considered-legacy features like segment limits. (For example, the ‘triple-fault in real mode’ trick of `mov sp, 1` / `push ax` does not work in pure-TCG QEMU.) KVM is based on the CPU’s native virtualization capabilities, which should make it more faithful to how it would run on bare metal.

Comment: You need the target formatted in FAT32 using Partition Magic or equiv then install these files https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg75e.png

Answer (score 2):

> First it threw an error message at me that I think was <strike>related to something about TSRs or some memory-related-something-or-other.</strike> (Actually, thinking about it more closely, I think the error was actually related to some sort of detected disk compression.) I think I had to use special switches to get the setup program to run. Then I believe it insisted on running ScanDisk before it would start the installation (?!). The installer finally did start, but it ended up crashing somewhere around the hardware detection part of the install.

> Is there any known reason for all of the interesting behaviors it exhibits?

Whatever was on the boot disk made assumptions about the hardware that just didn't apply to your VM, because probably the VM emulates much more modern hardware.

If you have something that emulates older hardware more faithfully (e.g. QEMU, properly configured), it'll likely run a lot better.

> (Bonus question though unrelated: When booting the Windows XP DOS disk, it would show an `A:\>` prompt at the top instead of a "Starting MS-DOS" message or some such. Underneath it would appear the real `A:\>` prompt. Why did that happen?)

IIRC that has something to do with `AUTOEXEC.BAT` running, so it's not "random".

Comment: Hmm, that would make sense of it. A DOS designed for XP-era hardware, trying to install 1995-era software on ~2019-era "hardware". Yep, that sounds like it would cause chaos now that you mention it.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 And the Windows install disk is not only "DOS designed for that hardware", it'll likely contain many special case checks for various models current in that area (because that's what Windows did), and those can easily go wrong on modern hardware. Which also explains why a "normal DOS disk" works so much better; it doesn't do any of those special checks.